# importNode SVG File contents being repeated - Visual Composer

Tags: jquery, svg

Im doing a project and using Visual Composer. Im working with some backend rendering. Im using importNode to grab the xml from a selected svg file on the server and print it. Everything works fine except for the fact it is printing the selected option in multiple elements.

Here is an image as to what im talking about. Whats going on here is the left box has the top svg shape selected, the middle box the heart and the right, the bottom shape. And it is echoing them in order across all 3 boxes, instead of printing just that boxes selected shape. [image]

Here is the jQuery im using to print the xml from the file. I tried wrapping this in a .each function and it duplicated it a second time stacking 6 shapes instead of just 3 haha. Im not necessarily a whiz at this by any means, any help is greatly appreciated

```
jQuery.get('../wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/svg/' + svg_type + '.svg', function(svgDoc) {
                    //import contents
                    var importedSVGRootElement = document.importNode(svgDoc.documentElement, true);
                    jQuery("span.my-svg-shape.outside").append(importedSVGRootElement);
                },"xml");
```

Im using that because, well because its the only thing I could get to work. However now that im actually building out a page I see it is printing more than 1 time, oddly nothing else is. Ive tampered with other aspects of the element such as the icon, that works fine.

Here is the code in full for the build of the element area we are dealing with.

```
var wrapper = jQuery('<div class="preview_element ' +
                        'image-box" style="width: 474px; max-width: 100%; ' +
                        'overflow: hidden;"></div>');
wrapper.append('<div class="img-wrap">' +
                        '<img class="attachment-large" width="474" ' +
                        'src="//placehold.it/474x355"></div>');
    jQuery.get('../wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/svg/' + svg_type + '.svg', function(svgDoc) {
                        //import contents
                        var importedSVGRootElement = document.importNode(svgDoc.documentElement, true);
                        jQuery("span.my-svg-shape.outside").append(importedSVGRootElement);
                    },"xml");
    wrapper.append('<div class="text-wrap">' +
                        '<span class="my-svg-shape outside ' + svg_type + '"></span><span class="my-svg-shape">' +
                        '<i class="fa ' + icon + '"></i>' +
                        '</span>' +
                        '<div class="callout-details-wrap">' +
                        content +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>');
                    wrapper.find('span.my-svg-shape.outside').css('fill', icon_bg_color);
                    }
```

As I said any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [Raphael Schweikert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11940/raphael-schweikert) this is the correct working snippet, see his comment.

```
jQuery.get('../wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/svg/' + svg_type + '.svg', function(svgDoc) {
                    //import contents
                    var importedSVGRootElement = document.importNode(svgDoc.documentElement, true);
                    wrapper.find('span.my-svg-shape.outside').append(importedSVGRootElement);
                },"xml");
```

Comment: I’m guessing the selector `span.my-svg-shape.outside` resolves to all three areas and thus you’re adding the loaded node to each of them (since `append` [“inserts content, specified by the parameter, to the end of _each_ element in the set of matched elements”](http://api.jquery.com/append/)). I could help you further if you show more of your code.

Comment: Sure what would you like to see... I will add the build out for the span.my-svg-shape.outside. If there is more you would like to see please let me know. I only put the importNode because I figured it was the only relevant code. I will add what it is appending to.

Comment: I added more of the code, I appreciate the help

Comment: You should probably use `wrapper.find('span.my-svg-shape.outside')` instead of `jQuery("span.my-svg-shape.outside")` so you only find one element to append the SVG to.

Comment: seeing your original comment, I believe you are correct. Typically, and as I said I am no whiz at this by any means, pretty noob, but learning, typically with Visual Composer it injects this code on a per element basis. So I assumed with append to the span it would only take the data for each element automatically. For instance the fill color is not duplicated.

Comment: Raphael, YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER.... Excellent it worked, changing to wrapper.find... Lesson learned, I will look closer in the future, the answer was right in my face. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert I have updated, linked your profile and upvoted your comment, Ive never had to mark my own question as correct, I dont see a way to do it. Thanks again my friend for the extra eyes, I really appreciate it.